# Blazor Server - Unable to send multiple http calls in blazor project with firebase cloud messaging (FCM) API

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm developing a Blazor Server application with .Net 6 where I need to send notifications using the Google Cloud Messaging (FCM) API. The first HTTP call works fine, but when I attempt a second call, I receive a '401 Unauthorized' error. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to make multiple HTTP calls without having to restart the page? In postman I don't have any issues doing multiple callings and is the exact same key that im using.

This is my function:

```
private async Task SendNotification()
{
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", key);

                    string mensajeJSON = $@"{{
                            ""data"": {{
                                ""WX_PUSH_EXT_VERSION"":""1.0"",
                                ""WX_PROP_TITRE"":""{NuevosDatos.Titulo}"",
                                ""WX_PROP_MESSAGE"":""{NuevosDatos.Msg}"",
                                ""WX_PROP_PRIORITE"":4,
                                ""WX_PROP_ACTIVEAPPLICATION"":true,
                                ""title"" : ""{NuevosDatos.Titulo}"",
                                ""body"" : ""{NuevosDatos.Msg}"",
                                ""priority"" : ""high""
                            }},
                            ""to"": ""/topics/{selelectedId.Name}""
                            }}";

                    request.Content = new StringContent(mensajeJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await http.SendAsync(request);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
//NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.Uri, forceLoad: true);
    }
```

And for the information im sending a Form using syncfusion

`````
<EditForm Model="NuevosDatos" OnValidSubmit="@EnviarDatos" OnInvalidSubmit="@MostrarMsgError">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md max-w-md mx-auto">

        <div class="mb-4">
            <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">Titulo</label>
            <SfTextBox Placeholder="Introducir Titulo" @bind-Value="@NuevosDatos.Titulo"></SfTextBox>

        </div>

        <div class="mb-4">
            <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">Mensaje</label>
            <SfTextBox Placeholder="Introducir mensaje" Multiline="true" @bind-Value="@NuevosDatos.Msg"></SfTextBox>

        </div>

        <div class="mb-4">
            <label class="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">Elige un tema</label>
            <InputSelect class="w-40" @bind-Value="NuevosDatos.TopicId">
                <option disabled selected>Elige</option>
                @foreach (var topic in listaTopics)
                {
                    <option value="@topic.Id">@topic.Name</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <SfToast @ref="ToastObj" CssClass="@toastClass" Content="@toastContent" TimeOut="@toastDuration">
            <ToastPosition X="Right" Y="Top"></ToastPosition>
        </SfToast>
        <div class="flex justify-end">
            <SfButton type="submit" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Submit</SfButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

````
`````